# What is a minimal bottleneck spanning tree?

Tags: graph-theory

My Algorithms professor gave us an exercise and the solution to that exercise, where I'm absolutely confused about the definition of a bottle neck spanning tree.

Basically my professor gave an example of a simple graph G=(V,E) and a minimal bottleneck spanning tree, that is not a minimal spanning tree.

G=(V,E), V={a,b,c}, E={{a,b},{b,c},{c,a}} (a triangle) and a weight function of w({a,b}) = 3, w({b,c}) = 1, w({c,a}) = 3.

A minimal spanning tree in this example would be obviously any spanning tree, that contains the edge {b,c}, because it has the weight of 1. But my professor says that an example for a minimal bottleneck spanning tree in this example would be T'=(V,E'), with E'={{a,b},{c,a}} with both w(e)=3 edges. How can this be a minimal bottleneck spanning tree, if it does not contain the minimal edge with w(e)=1?

Comment: How do you define "bottleneck tree"?

Comment: The definition is quite strange and unfortunately it is in another language. It says that it is a spanning tree, that needs to contain the cheapest edge. So in this example that would be that e with w(e)=1.

Comment: Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For bottleneck problems, you minimize the maximum rather than the sum.  In particular, the [MBST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bottleneck_spanning_tree) minimizes the maximum edge weight.

Comment: So in my example: when I create any spanning tree, I have to take an edge with w(e)=3. Therefore it is the maximum edge I'm allowed to take. So the tree with both w(e)=3 edges is in fact a minimal bottleneck spanning tree and so would be basically any tree in given example?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!